# getting the value from a checkbox in Matlab 2018

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am upgrading my Matlab from 2013b to 2018b and have found out that MathWorks have made quite a few changes to the GUI's.

One problem I am having is getting the value of checkbox. The line below is the code I used to use but now it doesn't work.

> if get(handles.check_perf_attr,'Value') == 1

The error message is,

> Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

So I tried the line below to just get the value that is being returned and then apply some logic.

> tValue = get(handles.check_perf_attr,'Value');

However tValue is 2 x 1 cell which in (1, 1) = 0 & (2, 1) = 1. I don't really understand this as surely a checkbox can only be one value true (1) or false (0)?

Comment: Huh, strange. According to https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.control.uicontrol-properties.html it should be a number (equal to Min property if unchecked and Max property if checked). If does that on my R2017a. Don't have a more recent one to test.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought, that it should be a number, thanks for testing on your version of Matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get` returns a cell array with values when applied to an array of handles.

Thus, I think your problem is that `handles.check_perf_attr` contains two handles, not one.

Comment: ah that sounds likely. Because the GUI worked in 2013 however I noticed one of the checkbox's was missing. So re-created it so that might make sense. How do I get rid of the other one if I can't see it?

Comment: @mHelpMe: How did you create the GUI? I usually create them programmatically, using `uicontrol` etc. If you did that, it's a matter of finding where in the code it is created. If you're using one of the GUIs to create a GUI, maybe the control ended up outside the window? Try enlarging it see if you can find it?

Comment: Thanks, you were correct in that the control had ended up outside the window

Answer (score 1):

"Dot notation is a new syntax to access object properties starting in R2014b."

so try

```
if handles.check_perf_attr.Value == 1
```

or

```
tValue = handles.check_perf_attr.Value;
```